# How do I awk or grep greppable Nmap output for IP address, Host, Port Number, Port Status, Protocol, Service, and Service Version (if there is one)?

Tags: awk, grep, nmap

The greppable Nmap output looks like the following:

```
Host: 9.2.1.100 (hello.world.com)       Status: Up

Host: 9.2.1.100 (hello.world.com)       Ports: 21/closed/tcp//ftp///, 22/closed/tcp//ssh///,
23/closed/tcp//telnet///, 25/closed/tcp//smtp///, 80/open/tcp//http//Citrix Metaframe ICA Browser/,
110/filtered/tcp//pop3///, 139/open/tcp//netbios-ssn//Microsoft Windows netbios-ssn/,
443/closed/tcp//https///, 445/open/tcp//microsoft-ds//Windows Server 2003 3790 Service Pack 2 microsoft-ds/,
3389/open/tcp//ms-wbt-server//Microsoft Terminal Service/        Seq Index: 256       IP ID Seq: Incremental
```

My question is how do I use awk or grep to parse the output so that I get the following:
IP Address, Host, Port Status (limited to only open ports), Protocol, Service, and Service Version (if there is one)?

```
9.2.1.100\thello.world.com\t80\topen\ttcp\thttp\tCitrix Metaframe ICA Browser\n
9.2.1.100\thello.world.com\t139\topen\ttcp\tnetbios-ssn\tMicrosoft Windows netbios-ssn\n
```

...

Comment: Stated that the port list starts in field #5, just iterate from field #5 to last one looking for the string `/open/`. You'd better use `awk`. You must bear in mind that one port info is separated from next one by a comma `, `.

Answer (score 0):

There are a million different ways to parse this output, and this is probably not the prettiest, but I do believe this should work:

```
grep 'Ports:' $1 | while read -r line
do
    ip=$(echo $line | grep -oP '(?<=^Host: )(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}')
    name=$(echo $line | grep -Po "(?<=^Host: $ip \()[^\)]*")
    echo "$line" | grep -Po '(?<=\tPorts: )[^\t]*\t' | sed -e 's/, /\n/g' | sed -e 's%/%\t%g' | cut -d/ -f 1-3,5,7 | sed -e "s/^/$ip\t$name\t/g"
done
```

in this specific example you have to save this code to a file and execute it with a the name of the file that contains the nmap output as an argument.
Anyway, [here](https://nmap.org/book/output-formats-grepable-output.html) you can find the full explanation about the grepable output of the nmap command. They even explain how it should be parsed, but i did not have the time to read it so i just wrote here this little script.
I hope you will find this helpful.